# DIV overlapping Masonary issues

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

[image]
    I am using jquery.masonry.js. when i used dynamic height div's then these div's overlap on each other.

I have tried

```
$('#all-posts').masonry({itemSelector : '.vc-post-inner'});
```

and tried many options but still it is giving same result.
these problem having only in google chrome not in mozilla firefox

Comment: Try this `resizesContainer : true,`

Comment: @davidStrada i tried this but not working

Comment: any reference links ?

Comment: I think the issue is caused by the container height and the images.  If "masonry" measures the content before the image is loaded then it might lead to this kind of issue. I would check if all images are loaded first, before initializing masonry.